# Question about this sentence "She tells him what to do"

Tags: grammar

I have a question about this sentence.

> She tells him what to do.

I am kind of confused on "him" and "what to do"

Would "him" be an indirect object, "what" be a noun and direct object, and "to" be an adjective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: "She" is the noun, "tells" is the verb, "him" is the *indirect* object of "tells," (see Colin Fine's comment below), and "what to do" is called a "*wh-clause.*" For more examples of wh-clauses, see this page: http://tinyurl.com/WH-CLAUSES

Note that if we ask the question, "Who tells him what to do?" we can answer with "She tells him." That is, the latter stands alone as a complete sentence.

Comment: I agree, except that I would  say that _him_ is the indirect object, and _what to do_ the direct. It is parallel with _She gives him the orders_.

Comment: @ColinFine Point taken. Thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering about your reason for asking the question. Is it in order to get a clarification of grammatical terms, or is it perhaps because you are not a native English speaker? In the latter case, I could easily understand your confusion.

My own opinion is that "him" in this sentence is an INdirect object (much like "She gives HIM the book"), and "what" is a relative pronoun, which is the object of the verb "tells." I admit that I have not heard of "wh- clauses" however!

Comment: Not quite - the clause "what to do" is the direct object. "What" is just part of it.